# Method links does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Im getting this error when i do like this. I want that my search is case insensitive. Any suggestion?

```
  $articles = Articles::whereHas('translations',function($query) use($search){
    $query->whereRaw('LOWER(`title`) like ?', array( $search))
    ->orWhereRaw('LOWER(`intro`) like ?', array( $search))
    ->orWhereRaw('LOWER(`content`) like ?', array( $search));
  })->get();
```

Comment: What collation does the table 'articles' have? If it's something_CI it means Case Insensitive and you'll need to convert it first

Comment: Then that's your problem. I've had similar problem not long ago and I'll post how I've solved it in a min.

Comment: Nevermind. I misunderstood your question. Your query should be case insensitive by default (since collation you're using). No real need for `LOWER(stuff)`.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with the query though. Are you sure you're not calling `$articles->links()` or `$articles->render()` in some view? Try putting `->paginate()` instead of `->get()`.

Comment: What error do you get? Also, are you sure (from the stack trace) that this bit of code is the culprit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @dev said you can get this error only when you're using `links()` method. What you need to do is:

1. Use `paginate(10)` instead of `get()`
2. Use `render()` instead of `links()` as latter was deprecated.